# Convert transparent PNG to System.Drawing.Icon in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icons, png

I'm looking to convert a transparent PNG image as an ImageSource into a System.Drawing.Icon that respects the transparency of the PNG.

WPF can somehow do this internally if you set the icon for a window to a PNG ImageSource, but is there any way I can do this manually? Specifically I need this to set the system tray notify icon and I really want to avoid using clumsy .ico format resources.

Comment: As a side note, windows vista+ supports .ico files which are actually in PNG format.  Does this work for you? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/22/10079192.aspx

Comment: Not unless there's some utility/function in .NET that I can use to build a .ico from a PNG on the fly... Good to know, tho.

Comment: @chaiguy have you looked at using http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon for doing WPF system tray stuff?

Comment: @MerickOWA That's actually the library I'm using--the problem with it is it expects the icon resource to be a System.Drawing.Icon and will throw an exception if it is not, hence my trouble.

Comment: @chaiguy Isn't the TaskBarIcon.IconSource property declared be an ImageSource?

Comment: @MerickOWA It is, but throws an exception if the underlying resource isn't a .ico file. :S

Comment: @chaiguy ah I see the problem now.  wpf-notifyicon is using System.Drawing.Icon to convert ImageSource to an HICON IntPtr for Shell_NotifyIcon.  It looks like your best option might be to write/find a function to wrap a PNG format image with the standard ico header and image directory.

Answer (score 6):

You can write

```
Icon.FromHandle(image.GetHIcon())
```

[You'll need to explicitly destroy the icon when you're done with it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle.aspx#70ef0fdd-b69c-4e01-9cee-1d98475f0fc8):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

DestroyIcon(newIcon.Handle);
```

Comment: Completely off-topic here, but congrats on the moderator election, @SLaks!

Comment: The problem here is that GetHIcon() is a method of Bitmap, not ImageSource, and there doesn't appear to be any sane way of getting a Bitmap from an ImageSource--the one method I found (which was about 20 lines long) doesn't preserve PNG transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for this~
Here is one, but not very good!

```
        Icon icon;
        Image source = Image.FromFile(picturefile, true);

        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(iconsize, iconsize,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target);
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, iconsize, iconsize);

        //target.Save("c:\\temp\\forest.bmp");

        icon = Icon.FromHandle(target.GetHicon());

        FileStream fs = File.Create(iconfile);
        icon.Save(fs);
        fs.Close();

        icon.Dispose();
        target.Dispose();
        source.Dispose();
```